# Sending the id of the respective component through a click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to send the id of the respective object through an on-click event , yet I always end up being sent the synthetic onClick event , how can I change this ?
How my array of objects looks like :

```
[
        {
            id:uuidv4(),
            data:[]
        }
    ]
```

My `onClick={(id)=>handleOpen(id)}`

EDIT: It was recommended to change the renderig of the button in the following way :

```
<button onClick={(e)=>addPieChartGroup(e.target.id)}>Add</button>
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do like that so when ever your items got update the map function adjust all index automatically

```
  const dataArray = [ { id:uuidv4(), data:[] } ]
    
    handleClick = (dataObj) =>{ console.log(dataObj) }
```

In render

```
dataArray.map((obj, index) => <Button id={index} onClick={handleClick(obj)}> Click Me </Button> )
```

Answer (score 0):

The first param inside the event handler is always the event itself. You are not changing anything by using `id`, except the argument name. That way you can access `event` by accessing `id` variable, **but your `id` variable still refers to `event`**.

You need to access the correct property to get the id.

`onClick={(event)=>handleOpen(event.target.id)}`

Comment: But I thought that e.target.id refers to the specific id of the button , not the id of the data it is based off, no ?

Comment: No, you will have to show how you are rendering the buttons in the question. You will have to attach it to some attribute, and you can access it accordingly. I assumed you are attaching to the `id` property.

Comment: I have just added how I render the button in the post,according to your comments, yet when I am trying to log the id in the passed function it's literally blank...

Comment: Because there is no id attached. I would request you to show how your array of objects relate to the button. Is there a map function? Show that too.

Comment: I have a bit of a hard time passing an id to each button because I dont know how to do it in a systematic way, as the "Add" button populates the state with another set of "id" and "data" - so it cannot be done through indexes - or at least I dont know how... I hope the above is sufficient to understand the context (yes , each component is mapped based of the above array of objects and the add button basically adds another object )

Answer (score -1):

you can pass id of button tag like this

```
const handleClick = (id) =>{
    console.log(id)
}

<Button id='myButton' onClick={(event) => handleClick(event.target.id)}
```

Comment: I have just done this , yet it logs a completely blank field for the id. Maybe because I dont have an id associated with the button , yet it is only located in my object?

Comment: you can also assign  your object index to your button ID ..so by that you will able to access that object by button assigned index

Comment: const dataArray = [
        {
            id:uuidv4(),
            data:[]
        }
    ]
 
dataArray.map(obj, index => 
       <Button id={index} onClick={handleClick(obj)}> Click Me </Button>
)
 
 handleClick = (dataObj) =>{
      console.log(Obj)
 }

Comment: I dont really know how to dynamically assign it with the index because the `Add` button populates the above array with another object and then I .map that object. How would I be able to access the ids without passing it through props (which imples building another component) ?

Comment: But if the items mutate (I can delete or add them) doesnt the index become a problem?

Comment: see my another answer.. it will help you